# by clicking upload button have to upload video from my system to my html page using HTML

Tags: image, upload, addition

I am trying to upload video from my system to my html page by clicking upload button using html.I am a beginners so pls help me.
Any ideas would be greatly.
thanks.

Comment: Please, post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by using HTML only. You need to use a programming language (such as PHP, ASP, Python, Java...) together with HTML. The logic is, your HTML form will post the file to your program and your program will hanlde it (move it to a desired folder for example). First decide which  language to use. (If you have no idea, I suggest PHP.) Then do a simple search in google such as "php file upload", you will find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
  choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

$target = "upload/";  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;  $ok=1;  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))  { echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; }
else { echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; } 
?>

and then you need build this php file in the same directory. if this is not what you want and you actually need is display a video in your html then you need write some javascript to deal with the video.